# Swift 5 Tab View (macOS) won't confirm to the width I've given

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

(Swift 5 in Xcode 10.3)

I've got a Tab View Controller with 3 tabs. I have the window in the Window Controller set to a minimum and maximum width of 1024. I have the Tabless Tab View set to a width of 1024. I have the View in each of the 3 tabs set to a width of 1024.  Yet when I run the app the tabs are at a width of 500px.

I've looked at the storyboard file in a text editor and there is nothing in there set to 500px or anything close and I can see all the 1024 widths I set in IB.

Prior to using a Tab View Controller I had a "plain" View Controller and it would display the correct width.  I added the Tab View Controller and removed the relationship between the Window Controller and the original View Controller, re-dragging from the Window Controller to the Tab View Controller.  I will be replacing the View Controller with the View Controller entirely once I re-design one of the tabs with what is on the original View Controller.  But I'm stuck here with this width issue.

Obviously I'm missing something but there is nothing in my code that sets a width and I don't see what in IB I'm missing.

Comment: Did or will you add constraints?

Comment: Well that was it.  I'd had it without constraints and with "reset to suggested constraints" and neither worked.  I'd even added a horizontal line that was full width which didn't work (and did "reset to suggested..").  All that is on the one tab right now is a button. So I added 4 constraints and bingo.  Thanks Willeke.  Sometimes this stuff is hard to glean from googling with all the different versions of Swift as well as not much being out there for macOS vice iOS.  I've got some books coming that will help.